# C++ Callback function

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, callback

I'm setting a timer using afxwin SetTimer function. This function receives three params one of which is a callback function.

I set a callback function in a class (let's call it NS) and tried to pass it as an argument. However the compiler complains that this:

```
void (__stdcall NS::*) (HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD);
```

is not the same as:

```
void (__stdcall *) (HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the function `static`*. Otherwise it's not even a function, but rather a *member* function, which is a very different animal. Moreover, it doesn't otherwise make sense to "pass the function in a class as a callback", as you put it: A non-static member function is tied to the state of an *object instance* of that class.

(Also, search this site, this question has been asked a million times over and there are many good alternatives spread out throughout SO.)

<sub>*) As @James points out, this is not sufficient if the callback function has a C interface, in which case you also need a free `extern "C"` wrapper function.</sub>

Comment: What I wanted was to pass the method member function, that's what I meant by the "function in a class", bad use of names. I guess it makes sense that you can't pass a member function for a callback of something that doesn't know your instance. All examples of callback I saw used member functions, so I wasn't gettig it. Also I may want to access the class variables, but now that you corrected my vocabulary, I was able to google this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SetTimer__non-static.aspx .

Comment: Also, I found this, it answer some questions I was left with: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html and it starts precisely by differentiating pointer-to-member-function from pointer-to-function.

Comment: Grand. As I said, this has been done to death and you should have no trouble finding an appropriate solution for your design.

Comment: If the interface is a C interface, making the function static is not enough, at least not formally.  Static functions can't be extern "C".  And an extern "C" function has a different type than an extern "C++" function.  Of course, VC++ doesn't enforce this, so if that's your only target, there's no problem.  Just be aware that it isn't legal C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, though that's an implementation detail. A free dispatcher function is probably the cleanest approach. I think the OP has found enough information, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not an implementation detail.  The C++ standard requires a diagnostic if you pass an extern "C++" function to an interface declared to take extern "C".  VC++ isn't conform in this respect, and doesn't enforce the rule, but it is a rule.  According to the C++ standard, you must use a free dispatcher function, and that function must be declared extern "C".

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh OK, thanks. I had forgotten that `extern "C"` is actually in the standard (I thought `extern` was just an opaque mechanism).