# Calling method inside of mouse hook code causes access violation

Tags: c++, firemonkey, mouse-hook, c++builder-xe8

I have a low level mouse hook which I am attempting to use to handle global left click events.  I have defined the hook in a base main form class like so:

```
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
private:
    HHOOK hMouseHook;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void __fastcall MouseHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
extern PACKAGE TMainForm *MainForm;
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TMainForm::MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MainForm->MouseHook(nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void TMainForm::MouseHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {

        HWND__ * handle = Platform::Win::WindowHandleToPlatform(this->Handle)->Wnd;

        RECT Rect;
        GetWindowRect(handle, &Rect);
    }
}
```

My mouse hook detects a left click just fine, however when I attempt to get the handle of my `MainForm` I get an access violation.

I originally thought this could be because I was trying to retrieve the handle in the `TMainForm` class, when in reality during run time, a form which inherits from `TMainForm` would be active.  So to do this, I wrote a virtual method called `GetHandle()`.

This function is defined in the `TMainForm` header like this:

```
virtual HWND__ * __fastcall GetHandle();
```

and in the inheriting class like this:

```
HWND__ * __fastcall TMainFormPass::GetHandle()
{
   return Platform::Win::WindowHandleToPlatform(this->Handle)->Wnd;
}
```

However, when I call `GetHandle()` in `TMainForm` I still get an access violation.  Additionally, after trying a few more things out, I realized that calling any virtual function at all from inside of `MouseHook` causes an access violation.

Why am I not able to retrieve my forms handle using   `Platform::Win::WindowHandleToPlatform(this->Handle)->Wnd;` inside of `MouseHook`?  Why does calling a virtual function inside of `MouseHook` cause an access violation?

Edit:

To test Remy's proposed answer of the MainForm pointer being invalid, I added a block of code to the `TMainForm` constructor to test if the pointer was valid.  Additionally, I added a block of code to the constructor of the class which inherits from `TMainForm` and is loaded when starting my application, to test its global pointer.  The global `MainForm` pointer in my `TMainForm` class was in fact invalid.  However, the global pointer for the inheriting class was valid, being that it was the class actually being instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe suggests that your global `MainForm` pointer is not pointing at a valid Form object when the hook is called.  Any call to a method of the form, such as `MouseHook()`, will thus have an invalid `this` pointer.  You must make sure you are assigning that pointer.

You are using the `SetWindowsHookEx()` example that I gave you in answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024712/call-setwindowshookex-with-method-defined-in-header-file).  In that same answer, I had also given you an alternative solution that did not involve `SetWindowsHookEx()` - handling the `WM_INPUT` message from the [RAW Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx).  Your question did not mention that you are using FireMonkey instead of VCL.  The example I had given you was for VCL.  I have now updated that answer to include a FireMonkey example as well.

Comment: @RemyLebau I appreciate you going out of your way with editing your answer to my other question!  I will definitely look into using RawInput.  I just wanted to see if I could learn what was going wrong in this case since I have everything all typed out.  In the case of the `MouseHook()` method, when you say it will have an invalid `this` pointer, is that referring to the hidden `this` pointer?

Comment: If the `MainForm` pointer used in the `MainForm->MouseHook(...)` call is invalid, the `this` pointer inside of `MouseHook()` will likewise be invalid, so `this->Handle` and other accesses of `this->` will fail. `MainForm` must be assigned, either by `Application->CreateForm()` at app startup, or `MainForm = new TMainForm(...)` somewhere in your code.  Also, if you keep using `SetWindowsHookEx()`, call `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` when the Form is destroyed. Even then, the hook can still be called again so set `MainForm` to NULL and have `MouseHookProc()` check for that before calling `MouseHook()`.